# Jmeter- Concatenate multiple results returned fro regular expression extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a regex that produce multiple matches and then i wanna to concatenate all result by comma separator ?

How can i do that ?

Here is the regex:

```
Regx       : data-rk="([^"]+)
template   : $1$
Match no.  : -1
```

I wanna the variable to have the value as :1,2,3

Note: when am using g modifier at the end of the regex no data is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code for to get array of regular expression data

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("value_matchNr"));
String delimiter = ",";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++) { 
 sb.append(vars.get("value_" + i));
 if (i == count){
 break; //to eliminate comma after the array
 }else {
  sb.append(delimiter);
 }
}
 vars.put("arrayOutPut",sb.toString());

 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Request :

[image]

Regular expression:
[image]

Response out:

[image]